# chmod: What does the `+a` parameter mean?

Tags: ubuntu, osx, chmod, bsd

I was following a tutorial and it told me to run

```
sudo chmod +a "SOME_PARAMS" some/dir
```

I was surprised to see that fail telling me

```
chmod: invalid mode: `+a'
```

So I wonder: What does the `+a` mode mean? How would I translate it into something Ubuntu understands? And I also like to know why it isn't universally supported.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is specific to macOS. From the `chmod(1)` on macOS:

> The ACL manipulation options are as follows:
>
> `+a`
> The `+a` mode parses a new ACL entry from the next argument on the command line and inserts it into the canonical location in the ACL. If the supplied entry refers to an identity already listed, the two entries are combined.

Answer (score 0):

The ACL is needed to set permissions sometimes.

I found a related instruction.
This document on web contents manual exlains about setting ACL for designated user.

https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Installing_Moodle#Download_and_copy_files_into_place

Comment: That seems to be a comment to another answer.